# Django how to use DateTimeField without microseconds?

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-rest-framework

My field in model:

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

it returns: `"created_at": "2023-02-21T09:24:55.814000Z"`

how can i get this one (without last part): `"created_at": "2023-02-21T09:24:55"`

Is there another way instead of this?
(part from the django rest framework serializer)

```
representation['created_at'] = instance.created_at.split('.')[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [strftime method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) to format the `datetime` in the way you want:

```
created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
# Should give "2023-02-21T09:24:55"
```

Generically in your APIs, [ISO-8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#:%7E:text=ISO%208601%20uses%20the%2024,hour%20between%2000%20and%2024.) should be preferred. You can use `created_at.isoformat()` to get the string representation in that format.